# How to use a .h file during execution without compiling it in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I have to use a header file after the program is compiled. This header is downloaded from a server due to a client petition. Inside the header there are 3 arrays and 1 int that I would like to read during execution.

My first solution is to write a parser. The header files always have the same pattern so I could write 4 lines to read the arrays and the int.

Is there any other solution? Perhaps a dynamic include and a precompiled header, ho knows.

---

This is the full explanation:

I'm developing a native Android application using Qualcomm AR SDK.

One technique to use your own 3D models is using this perl script: http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/. Basically you need 2 files: a header with vertices, normals and texture coordinates, and the texture. The above script can generetate this header from a .obj file.

Ok, now you have both files ready to use in native C/C++ to render the model. You can COMPILE this header and include it anywhere you want in your application. But my application needs to download this header and texture when the user presses a button, for example. The texture it's easy to read, but I also need to read the header at EXECUTION time. Because I am not a C/C++ expert I asked here if there was a chance to link the header at execution time.

But now it don't matter beacuse I've writed a parser so I can use the vertices, texture coords and normals at execution time.

Comment: `I have to use a header file before the program is compiled` That is how headers are typically used. What's wrong with `#include`ing the header in a single source file and using whatever is defined in it?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a header file like a configuration file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ is (usually) a *statically compiled* language. You compile it, and get some executable code out, which you can run. The two stages, before and after compilation, have nothing to do with each others. At compile-time, you deal with C++ source code *only*.

And at runtime, you deal with a single compiled program, generated from all the source code.

There is generally no way to "add" source code to a program once it has been compiled.

(I'm simplifying a bit here, I hope the nitpickers will forgive me)

What you need to do instead is treat that "header" as data, not code.

It is a data file containing three arrays and an int. You need to write your program to open that file, read its contents, parse it, and carry out the actions necessary.

To do that, you'll need to look into file I/O to load the file, string manipulation to process its contents, and then some logic to create the variables to hold the data specified in the data file.

But you can't just "plug in" new code.

Comment: +1 this is how answers are supposed to be handled. If only all of SO users were patient enough to remember the mission is to help programmers.

Answer (score 3):

No you have to write a parser. Some languages can incorporate new code while they are running, but C++ isn't one of them.

Comment: You might mention that there are ways to incorporate new code if it's already compiled (dynamic linking), but such methods are not relevant to OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement jalf's answer (now that the question has been re-opened... thank you) if your goal is to use constant values from a header, as a config file, implementing some simple regex parser should be sufficient.

Just make sure the variables you need to modify with the constants are actually variables, and not constants themselves, or you can't modify them at runtime.

ie. if you want to read MAX_FILES from config.h, don't compile using a default #define MAX_FILES 255, or const int MAX_FILES = 255. Use "int maxFiles = 255", then override it at runtime with your config value.

If I've misunderstood, apologies, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are trying to use a configuration file.  Do you have control over the format of the file on the server?  If so, the easiest method here would be to write your config files in a standard format like xml, then use a library like [rapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) to parse the config files as you receive them

The nice part about using a standard format is that if you decide to change your configuration file format later, add to it etc.  It will be a relatively easy update to your code to parse the updated file.  Typically less work than re-writing your custom parser.

If you don't have control over how the server files look, and they are not in a standard format like JSON, XML, YAML etc. you will have to write your own custom parser.  Sounds like it's a relatively simple file, so this shouldn't be too tough anyways.

Comment: It sounds pretty clear that the format is a C++ header file, that he receives from an external source.

Comment: In which case he should write his own custom parser as per the 3rd section of my answer.  I was just pointing out that if in fact he has some say in how this data is stored, it may be a better idea to make use of standardised data formats and parsers.  It's not particularily common to send C++ header files over a network. It really sounds like he's just trying to initialise some values in his program based on a text file from a server, and he's confused about how to include those values in his code (hence asking how to add a header into his compiled executable).